# React components not updating from Redux state after Hot Module Reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, hot-module-replacement

I am using react-hot-loader 3.0.0-beta.6 to hot reload react components. Reloading itself works well - i see the updated component immediately. Unfortunately, after successful reload, dispatching actions inside the application does not trigger rerenders any more and I need to do a full manual refresh to get the application working again. The dispatched actions update the redux store, but the components are not rerendered.

All the components I am using consist of a connected container and a stateless component.
What could be the reason for not rendering the updated state? How could I continue debugging?

MyComponent/container.js:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    ...
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({
    ...
  }, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

MyComponent/component.jsx:

```
const Component = ({ testProp1, testProp2 }) => (
  <div onClick={testProp2}>
    {testProp1}
  </div>
);
```

Here is the successful update:

```
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
[WDS] App hot update...
[HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
[HMR] Updated modules:
[HMR]  - ./source/modules/DropDown/index.js
...
[HMR]  - ./source/modules/App/index.js
```

Render in the main.jsx:

```
const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <App />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
        eyeTalLayer
    );
};

render();

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./modules/App', render);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually a couple open issues in the React-Redux repo discussing similar behavior as of React-Redux 5.0.  See [react-redux#636](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/636) and [react-redux#670](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/670).

I did a bit of research, and it looks like the components higher in the hierarchy are getting recompiled and hot-reloaded, but not the components lower in the hierarchy.  Because v5 implemented a top-down subscription system, the lower components aren't aware that their subscription references are now stale.  I haven't had time yet to try to figure out a good way to handle that.

Based on what I've seen, I believe that removing the use of React-Hot-Loader will work around the problem.  You could just reload the entire component tree using "plain" HMR, and I see you've already got your code set up to do that.  You'd lose the potential benefits of RHL trying to maintain component state, but the Redux connections *should* reset properly.

Comment: When i switched back to "react-redux": "^4.4.8", the problem disappeared.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would expect to see.  React-Redux 4.x does not enforce top-down subscriptions, so the behavior is different.